# How do you implement a 3 layer model with NHibernate?

Tags: .net, nhibernate

Taking the traditional 3 layer approach (not necessarily 3 tiers):

UI
BLL
DAL

How does NHibernate fit?  In most cases I see people allowing NHibernate to directly populate domain objects/entities, which obviously requires a reference from NHibernate to these entities.  If domain entities are part of the BLL, this seems to require a reference from the DAL (where NHibernate resides) to the BLL (where domain objects reside).

Doesn't this go against the typical thinking of separating each layer, with each layer only being dependent on the one below it?  What am I missing here?

Comment: You can go through [this link](http://www.primaryobjects.com/cms/article119.aspx) which illustrates the best way for designing layered NHibernate application using [Repository Model](http://www.primaryobjects.com/cms/article119.aspx)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I can give you an example, how I generally layer with NHibernate for a n-tier architecture:

**Data Access Layer**

- **NHibernate `SessionFactory`**
- **Mappings with [FluentNHibernate](http://fluentnhibernate.org/)**

*Example for a mapping:*

```
public class CategoryMap : ClassMap<Domain.Entities.Category>
{
    public CategoryMap()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

**Business Layer**

- **Repositories : BaseRepository**

*Example for a repository:*

```
public class CategoryRepository : BaseRepository<Domain.Entities.Category>,
    Domain.DataInterfaces.Business.Repositories.ICategoryRepository
{
    public CategoryRepository(ISession session)
        : base(session)
    {
    }
}
```

- **BaseRepository (CRUD, GetById, GetAll)**

*Example for a base repository:*

```
public class BaseRepository<T> : IBaseRepository<T>
{
    public ISession Session { get; set; }

    public BaseRepository(ISession session)
    {
        Session = session;
    }
 }
```

**Domain Layer**

- **DataInterfaces (IRepository, IBaseRepository)**
- **Entities : BaseEntity**
- **Persistance (IEntity, IBaseEnity)**

So, the only layer which is referencing NHibernate is actually the data layer and the business (`NHibernate.ISession`). The domain layer is shared between all layers and does not know about NHibernate. For simplicy you could merge the business and data layer into one layer. I generally tend to seperate them, but it depends on the project size.

[image]

If you really want seperation, I also suggest you to have a look at [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_Injection) to reduce the dependencies between different layers.

Hope that helps you.

Comment: Thanks Martin.  What exactly is NHibernate returning to the Business Layer?  Maybe a short code example would explain?

Comment: The DAL is only called by the BL and returns the NHibernate session and the NHibernate mappings. Nothing more. I added some examples, hope it becomes more clear.

Comment: Repositories shouldn't contain Business Logic... They should be in the DAL.

Comment: @Martin, Category is an entity in the domain model, correct?  The NHibernate session is going to return an instance of Category through the repository, correct?

Comment: @Casey: Yep, Category is an entity in the domain model. The NHibernate session factory holds the mappings which you access then through your repository.

Comment: @Casey: I guess it's important to understand that in my architecture the domain layer (which holds all the interfaces and entities) is actually shared between all these layers.

Comment: @Martin So NHibernate has a reference to the domain model, correct?

Comment: @Casey: No, the domain model contains only a simple DTO structure in its entities and the interfaces. It does not know about NHibernate or the DAL. Have a look at http://www.sharparchitecture.net/, if I'm not wrong and remember it right, they do it similar.

Comment: @Casey: I read your question again ;) Yes, the DL (NHibernate) references the domain layer.

Comment: NHibernate is the DAL. It is ok for the repository to contain business-logic, you can just call it a service in this case.

Comment: @Martin: I don't think SharpArch has a separate business layer that contains repositories. Repositories are DAL specific, for example they're NHibernate implementation in your code above and it may be completely replaced with another, for example, Entity Framework. Business logic is belong to Domain Layer, or in Application Service layer for more application specific logic.

Answer (score 4):

NHibernate is most suitable for a different architecture (still layered, but not stacked the same way).

The presentation layer uses NHibernate as a [Data Mapper](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html) (and [Unit of Work](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html)) to decouple its [Domain Model](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/domainModel.html) (that is, its business logic) from persistence concerns.

Comment: In the architecture you describe, what are the layers and how do they reference each other?

Comment: I'd say you get a **presentation layer** that knows about the **object-relational mapper** and **domain model** (business layer if you like), while the ORM also knows about the domain model.

Comment: This is exactly right. NHibernate is perfect for use with the onion architecture. See http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=onion+architecture.