# 3 Tier Architecture with NHibernate, Ninject and Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, nhibernate, dependency-injection, ninject

So I'm in the middle of rafactoring a small to medium sized Windows Forms application backed by a SQLite database accessed through NHibernate. The current solution contains only an App Project and Lib Project so it is not very well structured and tightly coupled in many places.

I started off with a structure like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4856130) but ran into some problems down the road.

1. **DB initialization:**
   Since the code building the NHibernate SessionFactory is in the DAL and I need to inject an ISession into my repositories, I need to reference the DAL and NHibernate in my Forms project directly to be able to set up the DI with Ninject  (which should be done in the App Project / Presentation Layer right?)

*Isn't that one of the things I try to avoid with such an architecture?*

*In an ideal world which projects should reference eachother?*

2. **DI in general:**
   I have a decently hard time figuring out how to *do DI properly*. I read about using a composition root to only have one place where the Ninject container is directly used but that doesn't really play well with the current way NHibernate Sessions are used. 
   We have a `MainForm` which is obviously the applications entry point and keeps one Session during its whole lifetime. In addition the user can open multiple `SubForms` (mostly but not exclusively) for editing single entities) which currently each have a separate Session with a shorter lifetime. This is accomplished with a static Helper exposing the SessionFactory and opening new Sessions as required.

*Is there another way of using DI with Windows Forms besides the composition root pattern?*

*How can I make use of Ninjects capabilites to do scoped injection to manage my NHibernate Sessions on a per-form basis (if possible at all)?*

3. **Terminology**:
   I got a little confused as to what is a `Repository` versus a `Service`. One comment on the posted answer states "*it is ok for the repository to contain business-logic, you can just call it a service in this case*". It felt a little useless with our repositories only containing basic CRUD operations when we often wanted to push filtering etc. into the database. So we went ahead and extended the repositories with methods like `GetByName` or more complex `GetAssignmentCandidates`. It felt appropiate since the implementations are in the Business Layer but they are still called repositories. Also we went with `Controllers` for classes interacting directly with UI elements but I think that name is more common in the Web world.

*Should our `Repositories` actually be called `Services`?*

Sorry for the wall of text. Any answers would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding 1:
Yes and no. Yes you would prefer the UI Layer not to be dependent on some specifics of x-layers down. But it isn't. The composition root is just residing in the same assembly, logically it's not the same layer.

Regarding 2:
Limit the usage of the container. Factories (for Sessions,..) are sometimes necessary. Using `static` should be avoided. Some Frameworks however prevent you from using the ideal design. In that case try to approximate as much as possible.
If you can currently do `new FooForm()` then you can replace this by DI or a DI Factory (p.Ex. [ninject.extensions.Factory](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.factory)). If you have absolutely no control on how a type is instanciated then you'll need to use `static` to access the kernel like a service locator and then "locate" direct dependencies (while indirect dependencies are injected into direct dependencies by the DI container).

Regarding 3: i think this is somewhat controversial and probably often missunderstood. I don't think it's really *that* important what you call your classes (of course it is, but consistency across your code base is more important than deciding whether to name them all Repository or Service), what's important is how you design their responsibilities and relationships.
As such i myself prefer to extract filters and stuff in the `-Query` named classes, each providing exactly one method. But others have other preferences... i think there's been enough blog posts etc. on this topic that there's no use in rehashing this here.

Comment: Took too long to edit my comment..

Part 2 was expecially helpful. If I understood you correctly I explicitly list my dependencies in the (Sub-)Forms and just use the factory for their initial creation similar to the creation of the MainForm in Program.cs. Then the factory provided by (in my case) Ninject can also resolve their dependency graphs and inject those.
In regards to the naming: I figured it wasn't really a big deal what to call them exactly. I was just making sure to not "violate" any established conventions.

Comment: re factory: yes exactly. Regarding naming conventions: well maybe they're somewhat established but I'm betting on them being misunderstood and broken *quite* frequently. So rather than adhere to them i would choose and define one that makes sense to your team and *document* it.

Answer (score 1):

Best practice to implement for situation like yours is to use **MVP** design pattern. Here its the architecture that i can offer to you.

1. MyApp.Infrastructure // Base Layer - No reference
2. MyApp.Models // Domain Layer - Reference to Infrastructure
3. MyApp.Presenter // Acts like controllers in MVC - Reference to Service, Models,
4. MyApp.Repository.NH // DAL layer - Reference to Models, Infrastructure
5. MyApp.Services // BLL Layer - Reference to Repository, Models
6. MyApp.Services.Cache // Cached BLL Layer(Extremely recommended) - Reference to Services, Models
7. MyApp.UI.Web.WebForms // UI Layer - Reference to all of layers

   I will try to do my best to explain with the example of basic implementation of 'Category' model.

**-Infrastructure-**

- EntityBase.cs
- BussinesRule.cs
- IEntity.cs
- IRepository.cs

**-Models-**

Categories(Folder)

- Category.cs // Implements IEntity and derives from EntityBase
- ICategoryRepository.cs // Implements IRepository

**-Presenter-**

***Interfaces***

- IHomeView.cs // Put every property and methods you need.
- ICategoryPresenter.cs

***Implementations***

- CategoryPresenter.cs // Implements ICategoryPresenter

  CategoryPresenter(IHomeView view, ICategorySevice categorySevice){

  }

**-Repository-**

Repositories(Folder)

- GenricRepository.cs // Implements IRepository
- CategoryRepository : Implements ICategoryRepository and derives from GenricRepository

**-Services-**

***Interfaces***

- ICategorySevice.cs
- AddCategory(Category model);

***Implementations***

- CategorySevice.cs // Implements ICategorySevice
- CategorySevice(ICategoryRepository categoryRepository ){}

  AddCategory(Category model){
  // Do staff by ICategoryRepository implementation.
  }

**-Services.Cache-**

// It all depents of your choose.. Radis or Web cache..

**-UI.Web.WebForms-**

Views - Home(Folder) // Implement a structure like in MVC views.
Index.aspx // Implements IHomeView

```
    Page_Init(){
        // Get instance of Presenter
        var categoryPresenter = CategoryPresenter(this, new CategorySevice);
   }
```

I'm not sure if i got your question correct, but maybe give you an idea:)

Comment: I don't think this example really fits my problem since we are developing a Windows Forms application and no ASP.NET web page. But thanks for your writeup anyway.

Comment: @MrFloya, Dear brother, It doesnt matter which UI you use with MVP:) MVP pattern just fits on well with Web Forms and also with WinForms. Just get instance of your presenter in FormLoad or FormInit events thats all. I strongly recommend you search about MVP.

Comment: You are right. Sorry I initially just glanced over your solution. Actually our current structure is very similar to MVP just naming conventions are a bit different.